# Passing and printing a value of string from controller to views in laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-blade

This is probably a very simple question.But I am stuck. This is my controller function where I am tryng to pass the sum of columns in the views to be printed at the end of a table

```
public function totalBillc3()
    {
      $total = Collection::where('collector_id', '=', 3)->sum('package');

      return View::make('users.collector3', compact('total',$total));



    }
```

And in the views I have written

```
             <tr>
               <td colspan="4" class="noborders"></td>
               <th class="text-right" scope="row">TOTAL</th>
               <td class="text-right">{{ $total}}</td>
            </tr>
```

I have my route setup perfectly but the error is showing

```
Undefined variable: total (View: /Volumes/G/zipbillingsoft.com/resources/views/users/collector3.blade.php).    Please help.
```

Answer (score 1):

`compact()` takes one or more strings as arguments, then looks for variables named like those strings.

In other words, you should not do

```
compact('total', $total)
```

but rather just

```
compact('total')
```

And if you have multiple variables, do

```
compact('total', 'something', 'something_else')
```

Documentation: http://php.net/compact

Comment: How to print it in my view?

Comment: `{{ $total }}` exactly like you do.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in you View::make in using function `compact`. Try the following code:

```
return View::make('users.collector3', compact('total',['total']));
```

Comment: How to print it in my view?